# What causes this unterminated entity ref exception with android's XMLPullParser?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting an unterminated entity ref error in a very simple android app I've been working on. What I'm trying to do is grab an xml file from the internet which contains a restaurant menu with different sections, and then display a list of the menu items. When I use the sample XML provided by [this](http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml) tutorial (and change the names of the fields it's looking for) it works as intended, but when I use the menu I actually want (link removed) it doesn't work.

This is the method I've written to test things. I've removed everything the but the basics and still have the problem:

```
public void parseXMLTest(XmlPullParser parser)throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    Log.d("menu","About to Parse...");
    int eventType = parser.getEventType();
    while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        switch(eventType) {
            case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                Log.d("menu","Stat Doc");
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                Log.d("menu","Stat Tag");
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                Log.d("menu","End Tag");
                break;
        }
        eventType = parser.next();
    }
    Log.d("menu","End Doc");

}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
10-22 16:25:07.028    5318-5318/com.example.jake.purduefood W/System.err﹕ org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unterminated entity ref (position:TEXT @1:1726 in java.io.InputStreamReader@41bc3bd0)
10-22 16:25:07.028    5318-5318/com.example.jake.purduefood W/System.err﹕ at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readEntity(KXmlParser.java:1210)
10-22 16:25:07.028    5318-5318/com.example.jake.purduefood W/System.err﹕ at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readValue(KXmlParser.java:1392)
10-22 16:25:07.028    5318-5318/com.example.jake.purduefood W/System.err﹕ at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:390)
10-22 16:25:07.028    5318-5318/com.example.jake.purduefood W/System.err﹕ at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:310)
10-22 16:25:07.028    5318-5318/com.example.jake.purduefood W/System.err﹕ at com.example.jake.purduefood.MainActivity.parseXML(MainActivity.java:131)
10-22 16:25:07.028    5318-5318/com.example.jake.purduefood W/System.err﹕ at com.example.jake.purduefood.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
10-22 16:25:07.028    5318-5318/com.example.jake.purduefood W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
10-22 16:25:07.028    5318-5318/com.example.jake.purduefood W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
10-22 16:25:07.028    5318-5318/com.example.jake.purduefood W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2541)
10-22 16:25:07.028    5318-5318/com.example.jake.purduefood W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641)
10-22 16:25:07.028    5318-5318/com.example.jake.purduefood W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
10-22 16:25:07.028    5318-5318/com.example.jake.purduefood W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
10-22 16:25:07.028    5318-5318/com.example.jake.purduefood W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-22 16:25:07.028    5318-5318/com.example.jake.purduefood W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
10-22 16:25:07.028    5318-5318/com.example.jake.purduefood W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)
10-22 16:25:07.028    5318-5318/com.example.jake.purduefood W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 16:25:07.028    5318-5318/com.example.jake.purduefood W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-22 16:25:07.028    5318-5318/com.example.jake.purduefood W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
10-22 16:25:07.028    5318-5318/com.example.jake.purduefood W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
10-22 16:25:07.028    5318-5318/com.example.jake.purduefood W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Also, this is my first post here on StackOverflow so if I'm not asking this correctly or need to change something please let me know! I'd really appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xml is [not valid](http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.hfs.purdue.edu%2Fmenus%2Fv1%2Flocations%2FEarhart%2F10-01-2014).  You should talk with whomever is generating it.

There's a top level `</script>` tag too.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't think of that. So I guess my code was alright after all. Thank you very much!